# Flash/Actionscript - How can I post a tweet from a swf (without using a server-side proxy such as Tweetr)?

Tags: flash, actionscript, twitter

How can I post a tweet directly to twitter without needing to use a server-side proxy script (ie, tweetr)? Can a twitter API call be made directly from a swf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think if it's possible to do this without a proxy (I've been trying for awhile now).
Twitter's crossdomain.xml file used to allow any Flash application to make API calls, but due to security issues, they decided to change their cross domain file and make it much more restrictive (which actually crippled a lot of flash applications). I believe it's possible to use the Twitter API from a desktop Flash (AIR) application, but if you're trying to do so from the web, you're going to need a proxy. I unfortunately cannot get the Tweetr proxy to work myself, so I am searching for an alternative way. If I find one, I'll be sure to post it here.

Comment: hi @Arms, do you know how to access the twitter api from an AIR app withut using proxy?

Comment: Nope. I ended up using some PHP scripts I wrote to handle whatever requests I needed to make. But this was a year ago, so maybe Twitter's changed something on their end I'm not aware of.